# How to execute one python script in a different directory with another script?

Tags: python, import

I am trying to execute one python script (file2.py) through the other (file1.py). 
The first file is located in test/file1.py and the second file in test/test1/file2.py.

As an example file2.py has the following code:

```
file = open("textfile.txt","w") 
file.write("Hello world")
file.close()
```

so I am trying to create a .txt file from file1.py. 
To do so, I have tried several solutions such as:

```
import Test1.file2
```

or

```
import os 
os.system('Test1/file2.py')
```

or

```
from subprocess import call
call('Test1/file2.py', shell='True')
```

in file1.py but none of them seem to work. The first solution works well if I want to import a function but it does not work when I want to create a text file.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: There's a difference between `import Test1` and `import test1`. Python is case sensitive. And depending on which python version you're rocking, you might need to create a `__init__.py` script in the `test1` folder. Was a while since I did this, but that usually helps. You can also have a look at [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-programmatically) which does this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the other file, you have some options:

The best one is to treat the file as a module, import it, and call it's methods, so you would have to encapsulate the .txt creating inside a method

```
#on file1.py
def createTxt():
    #your txt creation goes here
```

and call `createTxt` from `file2.py` importing `file1.py`, which will run the method and create the txt file

```
#on file2.py
import file1

createTxt()
```

You can also use `execfile('file2.py')` to execute it and run it as a script or make a system call with `os.system('python file2.py')` importing `os` to also run as a script

The first one is safer and a better code in general, avoid using the other two when possible